# How to reset all margins and paddings within a parent element?

Tags: html, css

I know this is how you reset all margins and paddings for the whole site,

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

but how do I reset the margin and parent of all elements that are within a certain css ID?

is it just

```
#element * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
```

?

Comment: Yes, but you should write `#element, #element *` if you want to reset the margins on #element itself as well.

Comment: Would've been equally as quick to just test it yourself than ask. I'd avoid `*`, by the way.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ OK, I'll bite. How would you rewrite the OP's selector so that it doesn't use `*`?

Comment: @MrLister - impossible to answer without more detail. I'm not going to ask for more detail since it's not the question he originally asked. Which is why I posted it as a comment. To target *everything* universally in CSS is bad practice. Are there legitimate scenarios whereby you'd recommend using a wildcard in CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use  `#element,#element *` means to parent and to child of parent

```css
#element,#element *{
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div id="element">
  <div>child
  </div>
  <div>child
  </div>
  <div>child
  </div>
  <div>child
  </div>
</div>
```